# how to display the array values in checkbox using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code

```
$val= $module[$i]['subModule'];
$val1=$module[$i]['submoduleId'];
$valArr['name'] = explode(",", $val);
$valArr1['id']= explode(",", $val1);
$result=array_merge($valArr,$valArr1);
foreach($result as $name)
{
    if(!empty($name))
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='type[]' value='".$name['id']."'>".$name['name']." ";
    }
}
```

It show the undefined index error.

I print the $result variable I got the following output:

```
Array ( [name] => Array (
                  [0] => group
                  [1] => checkin
                  [2] => personalinfo 
                 ) 
         [id] => Array ( 
                  [0] => 3 
                  [1] => 2
                  [2] => 1 
                 )
      )
```

Comment: _"It show the undefined index error."_ Please include the error, what variable / index is undefined?

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try This Code:**

```
foreach($result['name'] as $key => $name){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='type[]' value='".$result['id'][$key]."'>".$name." ";
}
```